# Extjs 3.3 dynamically add fields to a form and set their labels width

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I need to set the labelWidth property after calling doLayout on a form.

It seems that after the form has been rendered sequence requests to the do layout are ignoring the labelWidth property of the form, and are set to a 100px default.

```
Nipendo.ProformaInvoice.View = Ext.extend(Ext.FormPanel,{
     constructor: function (config) {
        if (!config) {
            Nipendo.showError({ title: 'Error', message: 'A error occurred while loading the invoice view. A configuration element is missing.' });
            return;
        }

        if (!config.invoice) {
            Nipendo.showError({ title: 'Error', message: 'A error occurred while loading the invoice view. The invoice element is missing.' });
            return;
        }

    this.topToolbar = this.creatTopToolbar();

    this.invoice = config.invoice;

        var items = this.createDefaultLayout();

        config = Ext.apply({
            labelWidth: 140,
            bodyStyle: 'padding:2px 5px;',
            autoScroll: true,

            tbar: this.topToolbar,

            items: items
        }, config);

        Nipendo.ProformaInvoice.View.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    }, // eo constructor

    // private
    handelBackToDefaultView: function (switchToView) {
         if (this.currentViewName == 'sidebyside') {
             this.removeAll();

             this.currentViewName = switchToView;

             this.add(this.createDefaultLayout());

             this.doLayout();
         }

         this.currentViewName = switchToView;

     }, //eo handelBackToDefaultView
})
```

after calling the handelBackToDefaultView all of the labels are being set to 100px.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem by my self,

Issue was that the new side by layout that I have created did has created a new panel as a first item of the form, that panel was missing the labelWidth property to inherent all of the inner fields.